# Integration with respect to a parameter $a$

Tags: definite-integrals

Show that the value of the integral of $$\frac{\log(1+\cos(a)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}$$ over the interval $[0,\pi]$ is given by $$\pi\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - a\right)$$ for $0\leq\,a\leq\,2.$

Comment: Integrate $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, considering that $a$ is constant.

Comment: Is $\log$ with base 10 or $e$?

Comment: Sorry about that. The question merely stipulates 'Log'

Comment: I believe you can get some mileage on this by letting $I_a = \int_0^\pi \frac{\log(1+\cos(a)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}\,dx$ and then considering $I_a' = \frac{d}{da}I_a$.  Then by using the symmetry $\pi-x$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$ I believe one can simplify the expression for $I_a'$.  But I haven't yet reached a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by defining 
$$
I_a = \int_0^\pi\frac{\log(1+\cos(a)\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}\,dx.
$$
Observe that $I_{\pi/2} = 0$, so we would be done if we could prove that $I_{a}' = -\pi$, where the derivative is with respect to $a$.  So taking the derivative under the integral sign, we get
$$
I_a' = -\sin(a) \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1+\cos(a)\cos(x)}.
$$
Performing the change of variables $y=\pi-x$, we can also see that 
$$
I_a' = -\sin(a) \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1-\cos(a)\cos(x)}.
$$
Taking the average of the two integrals, and summing the fractions we arrive at
$$
I_a' = -\sin(a) \int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{1-\cos^2(a)\cos^2(x)}
 = -2\sin(a)\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{1-\cos^2(a)\cos^2(x)}.
$$
In the second step we used the symmetry of the integrand with respect to the swap $x\mapsto \pi-x$.

To proceed with this integral, we now use the change of coordinates $u=\tan(x)$.  Then $\cos^2(x) = (1+u^2)^{-1}$ and $(1+u^2)^{-1}du = dx$, so
$$
I_a' = -2\sin(a)\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{u^2+1-\cos^2(a)} = -2\sin(a)\int_0^\infty \frac{du}{u^2+\sin^2(a)}.
$$
Now we make another change of variables $u = \sin(a)v$ to simplify further:
$$
I_a' = -2\int_0^\infty \frac{dv}{v^2+1} = -\pi.
$$
where the last equality can be proven using the trigonometric substitution $v = \tan(\theta)$.

Comment: Superb ! Got it ! Thanks very much indeed

Comment: No problem, it was fun to solve!  By the way, if this answers your question it is good practice to accept the answer, so that others know that this solution is satisfactory, and it's a way to reward the people that take the time to work on your questions :)

Comment: I accept the solution and am extremely grateful to those who contributed to the solution.

Comment: @Callie12 you should go on the arrows top left of the brilliant answer of felipeh and choose his answer as the best answer. Only you can do that and it's the way to give credit, in points, to the answerer

Comment: Thanks hopefully all ok now.